# Bounded function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function  $f: [0,T)\to \Bbb{R}$ continuous and bounded on $[0,T)$
and all its higher derivatives are also bounded on $[0,T)$.

Then can we say that this function has a limit when $t$ tends to $T$ ?? is there any theorem that implies this result or is it false?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity $f(t) - f(s) = \int_s^t f'(s)\, ds$.

Since $f'$ is bounded (by $C$), $$f(T_n)-f(T_m) \leq |T_n-T_m|C$$ so $T_n \to T$ implies $f(T_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. therefore converges

Comment: Thank you this is very reasonable

Answer (score 0):

Every uniformly continuous $f(x)$ function on $[0,T)$ has a limit as $x\to T^-.$ The proof: Let $x_n \to T^-.$ Show $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy, just as Conrado Costa did.

In particular, any function $f$ differentiable on $[0,T)$ with bounded derivative there is uniformly continuous by the MVT, hence has the desired limit.

Comment: then i understand that to have the satisfied limit the higher derivatives should be also  bounded  if they are not then we do not have the limit .

Comment: No, that's not true: On $[0,1)$ consider $f(x) = \int_0^x\sin(1/(1-t))\,dt.$ Then $f'(x)= \sin(1/(1-x)),$ which is bounded on $[0,1),$ but

$$f''(x) = [\cos(1/(1-x))]/(1-x)^2,$$

which is unbounded on this interval (check along the sequence $1-1/(2n\pi)$ for example).